# Could not resolve react-native peer dependency

Tags: react-native, dependencies, npm-install

I cloned a react native repository and I am getting the following errors when I perform `npm install`.

It seems like 2 packages have peer dependencies with the react-native package:

- react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.17.5
- react-native-svg-icon@0.10.0

The package.json file has `"react-native": "0.68.2"`, which seems to be compatible with what react-native-async-storage package needs (`react-native@"^0.0.0-0 || 0.60 - 0.68 || 1000.0.0"`) and same with react-native-svg-icon@0.10.0 (`react-native@"^0.64.0"`)

I tried `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps` commands, some vulnerabilities are solved but same output for `npm install`.

Any suggestions?

When running `npm install`:
[image]

When running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`:[image]

When running `npm install --force`:[image]

Comment: Would you post the error log that you get after running ```npm install --legacy-peer-deps``` ?

Comment: Thanks for answering @sush. I just edited the post with the screenshot for `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` and `npm install --force`

Comment: Seems like legacy-peer-deps option did not throw any error. Did it not install the packages ? What happens when you do ```npm start``` ?

Comment: Also never post screenshots of error. Please post them in reproducible(text) form going forward.

Answer (score 0):

What eventually worked for me was to downgrade npm's version, in my case it was 8.3.1.